# PHP values going into db on refresh

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Im trying to create something that if a user choses a match is going to win and that match wins the points enter automatically into DB .. Im doing fine untill the point that points enter only one time into DB. I mean validating properly but everytime on refresh points enter into DB . Help Please.

```
//Ndeshjet e fituara ose jo
echo "<h3>Ndeshjet e vendosura nga <b>$username</b> dhe Rezultatet:</h3><br/>";

$query = $db-> query("SELECT * FROM match_select WHERE user_id='$username'");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){                         
    $match = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `winner` WHERE `user_id` = '$username' AND  `match_id` = '$id' AND `liga`='$liga'");

    $id = $row['match_id'];
    $liga = $row['liga'];
    $koeficent = $row['selected_koef'];     

    if($match->rowCount($match)){       
        echo "";            
    }else{
        if ($row['result'] == $row['final']){
            $hey =  "style='color: green;' ";
            $match = $db -> query("INSERT INTO winner (user_id, match_id, koef, final, liga) VALUES ('$username','$id', '$koeficent', '1', '$liga')");
        }else if ($row['final']== ""){
            $hey =  "style='color: black;' ";
        }else{
            $hey =  "style='color: red;' ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seperate your php code from your display code, so it wont re-execute. IE page1 post to script.php which produces no output and redirect `header("Location:page2.php");exit();` to page2. You can then click back, forward, refresh all you like, but script.php will only run when the form is submitted

Comment: I don't want to submit a form. i want to update db for the user if he won a match only once.

Comment: Ah! so you really need to check if $username has already tried, by recording it in the database (regardless if they win) and check this before executing your code (ie you have already tried and Won/Failed)

Comment: Thats exactly what im trying to do. with the form i tried it and it works perfectly but i want this as another option. if i can get this to work, form will be out of play

Comment: your going to have to provide more information and add comments to your code to explain what your trying to do

Comment: Oh man, as a side note, do some parameter quoting to prevent from SQL injection, will you? ...or nevermind, just give me address of your site, I hadn't won anything lately and gladly hack myself to hall of fame.

Comment: Thats the only thing im trying to do .. check if the logged in user already got the points if his match (that he picked) won and if not enter automatically

Comment: One suggestion - get the inserting code out of this place (it doesn't belong here anyway) and put it into the place where you're creating/updating match_select row. There is a place in your code when you actually insert 'final' value which is same as 'result' value, right? That's the place to go, not the display

Comment: The final value is inserted by the admin directly into the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In respect to the code provided and as I understand it;

1. Select all the matches for that username (loop through all matches)
2. Validation: check if this has been added to the winner table already
3. If so ignore it, otherwise if result = final is same (don't know the context here) then store..

The problem is when you select data for validation, they are null value you should declare them before query...as here

```
$match = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `winner` WHERE `user_id` = '$username' AND  `match_id` = '$id' AND `liga`='$liga'");

$id = $row['match_id'];
$liga = $row['liga'];
$koeficent = $row['selected_koef'];
```

it should be

```
 $id = $row['match_id'];
 $liga = $row['liga'];
 $koeficent = $row['selected_koef'];       
 $match = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `winner` WHERE `user_id` = '$username' AND  `match_id` = '$id' AND `liga`='$liga'");
```

This coluld be the reason when refereshing everytime it doesn't find any results so inserts.... my recommendation is to have SQL in a different variable and for testing purposes you can dump it on screen such as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `winner` WHERE `user_id` = '$username' AND  `match_id` = '$id' AND `liga`='$liga'";
echo $sql; //to see whats going on
$match = $db->query($sql);
```

**Hope this helps mate**

Comment: Thanks bro .. That was a dumb mistake from my end. Didn't even notice that i was senting NULL values